# Getting SIGSEGV when using cout << boolalpha in constructor function

Tags: c++, g++, clang++

I wrote `cout << boolalpha;` inside constructor function, like :

```
void BeforeMAIN() __attribute__((constructor));
void BeforeMAIN()
{
  cout << boolalpha;
}
```

And I am getting `SIGSEGV`.

Have a look : [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94edf317979cab8b)

`gdb` says :

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7b64f97 in std::ostream::operator<<(std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

It seems like object `cout` or `boolalpha` has not been instantiated when `cout << boolalpha;` is called. So my question is, when actually `BeforeMAIN()` is called, and why I am getting `SIGSEGV` and any other relevant information.

Comment: The gcc-specific `__attribute__((constructor))` syntax causes code to be invoked when a shared library is loaded.  It may be the case that you are linking your standard runtime libraries dynamically, which means that your code may be invoked at the moment the standard runtime libraries are loaded but before they are initialized. So, `cout <<` is invoked but none of the stuff it needs to work with have been initialized.  Try statically linking the standard runtime libraries to verify whether this is indeed the case.

Comment: You get that information by reading the [GCC online mnual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/), especially the section about [function attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes). However, it doesn't actually say when the constructor functions are called in relation to the C++ runtime initialization, so you should probably assume the order is undefined and you can't assume global objects have been constructed. Probably also related to [the static initialization order fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: @M.M I wrote all such code in a different file and just include it. No need to write again and again.

Comment: what's that got to do with anything?  If you want to run some code before main, but after `cout` is constructed, there is a language construct for exactly that